# Strange error in Biber

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am getting a strange error that I do not understand upon the compilation of the bibliography using Biber:

> :2620: parser error : Premature end of data in tag section line 2218 ^
>   :2620: parser error : Premature end of data in tag controlfile line 2
>   ^
>
> INFO - This is Biber 2.1 INFO - Logfile is 'THESE_docm.blg' INFO -
>   Reading 'THESE_docm.bcf'
>
> Process exited with error(s)

My bibliography do not compile and I do not understand this error - the main document compiles fine with XeLaTex - so I do not know where or what to look for. Biber compiles normally for another latex document, I tried cleaning the output files but it still does not compile. I even tried commenting the whole document.

Any clue what I could do?
Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{docmute}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[hyperref=true,
            url=true,
            doi=true,
            natbib=true,
            backref=true,
            backrefstyle=three,
            backend=biber,
            refsegment=chapter,
            citestyle=numeric-comp,
            style=chem-rsc,
            maxcitenames=5,
            date=year,
            block=none,
            maxbibnames=100]{biblatex}

%%%%%%

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    backrefpage  = {\it\footnotesize Cited on page}, % for single page number
    backrefpages = {\it\footnotesize Cited on pages} % for multiple page numbers
}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{hung2010practical,
  Title                    = {On the practical aspects of recording wideline QCPMG NMR spectra},
  Author                   = {Hung, Ivan and Gan, Zhehong},
  Journal                  = {J. Magn. Reson.},
  Year                     = {2010},
  Number                   = {2},
  Pages                    = {256--265},
  Volume                   = {204},
  Doi                      = {10.1016/j.jmr.2010.03.001},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text.\cite{hung2010practical}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please try the following code and report any strange things: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Zitiere Onlinequelle: \cite{ctan,markey}\par
Zitiere Buch: \parencite{companion}\par
Zitiere Artikel: \cite{springer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}`

Comment: This can happen if the xelatex run was faulty and didn't produce a complete bcf-file. Delete the bcf, and rerun xelatex.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with this file, it compiles fine ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried deleting the file, and recompiling, I still get the same error. The bcf file finishes by :          <bcf:citekey order="280">Iuga2003</bcf:citekey>
    <bcf:citekey order="281">TheMathWorksa</bcf:citekey>
    <bcf:citekey order="282">bak2000simpson</bcf:citekey>
    <bcf:citekey order="283">topspinuserguide</bcf:citekey>

Comment: Looks as if your tex file is faulty. Try to make a complete, small example.

Comment: I will have a go, but it is a very large document.

Comment: Just in case `biber's cache` is corrupted: delete the directory `C:\Users\Your_Name\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4265726e617264` (the sequence of numbers may be different) and start again the compilation cycle.

Comment: I found the problem ! All came frome loading the package docmute (See edited post).

Comment: @HcN Can you remove the answer from your post and turn it into an answer? That makes it easier for people with the same issue to see that your question has a solution.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer "This can happen if the xelatex run was faulty". It also happens when pdflatex run was faulty and, usually, rerunning it is enough. It is nevertheless quite annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update the 29th of November 2015:** It would seems that this problem no longer appear after updating the `biblatex` package.

Found the problem ! It came from loading the package `docmute` that I planned to use in the futur. All I had to do was to load `docmute` after `biblatex` and now everything compiles fine.

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[hyperref=true,
            url=true,
            doi=true,
            natbib=true,
            backref=true,
            backrefstyle=three,
            backend=biber,
            refsegment=chapter,
            citestyle=numeric-comp,
            style=chem-rsc,
            maxcitenames=5,
            date=year,
            block=none,
            maxbibnames=100]{biblatex}

%%%%%%
\usepackage{docmute}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    backrefpage  = {\it\footnotesize Cited on page}, % for single page number
    backrefpages = {\it\footnotesize Cited on pages} % for multiple page numbers
}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{hung2010practical,
  Title                    = {On the practical aspects of recording wideline QCPMG NMR spectra},
  Author                   = {Hung, Ivan and Gan, Zhehong},
  Journal                  = {J. Magn. Reson.},
  Year                     = {2010},
  Number                   = {2},
  Pages                    = {256--265},
  Volume                   = {204},
  Doi                      = {10.1016/j.jmr.2010.03.001},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text.\cite{hung2010practical}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does that mean that citation work as well, or is it only that the warnings disappear? In [#348](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/348) the handling of malformed `.bcf` files has been changed.